# SQL : Getting max ID row within a substring

Tags: sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

This is my first call for help, most of the time I have been able to figure out from google searches into StackOverflow but this time I can't seem to find an answer or don't understand fully the amswers that are already out there.

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 = T1.

```
Columns ID1, ID2, TITLE
Value    1, D1, TITLE1
         2, D2, TITLE2
         3, D3, TITLE3
         .....
```

Table 2 = T2.

```
Columns ID1, Rev, CODE
Value    1, 1, V1
         1, 2, V2
         1, 3, V3
         1, 4, V4
         2, 1, V5
         2, 2, V6
         2, 3, V7
         3, 1, V8
```

Ideally I want to return the max value of Rev from T2, toegther with column ID2 from T1. So the results should look like this.

```
Columns T1.ID2, T1.TITLE, T2.REV, T2.CODE
            D1, TITLE1, 4, V4 
            D2, TITLE2, 3, V6
            D3, TITLE3, 1, V8
```

This is my attempt and overall I think I am on the right path but it could be some messed up syntax.

```
SELECT T1.ID2, T1.TITLE, 
        SUBSTRING(

                SELECT MAX(T2.REV)
                FROM  T2 T2B
                WHERE T2B.ID1 = T1.ID1)
                AS MAXREV, 
    T2.CODE
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.ID1 = T2.ID1
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Which SQL language?  MySQL?  T-SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
 with maxt2 as 
(
 select id1,max(rev) as maxrev
 from t2
 group by id1
)
select t1.id2,t1.title,maxt2.maxrev
from maxt2 m join t1 t 
on m.id1=t.id1
order by 1,2 desc
```

Comment: If you are using TSQL this should give the results that you require

Comment: For this specific problem (where you can guarantee that you only have one row that is the maximum value) this is the better solution.  I jumped into the deep end with mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses T-SQL (MS SQL Server) specific syntax, in fact it only works in SQL Server 2008 and later.

For a MySQL solution, I just posted a solution using the same technique here:  [How to select latest date from this query (not in a existing table)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340428/how-to-select-latest-date-from-this-query-not-in-a-existing-table/45341134#45341134) with guidance on this method from here:  [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

The T-SQL solution is (including setting up table vars):

```
declare @t1 table (id1 int, id2 varchar(10), title varchar(20));
declare @t2 table (id1 int, rev int, code varchar(20));

insert into @t1 (id1, id2, title) values (1, 'D1', 'TITLE1');
insert into @t1 (id1, id2, title) values (2, 'D2', 'TITLE2');
insert into @t1 (id1, id2, title) values (3, 'D3', 'TITLE3');

insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (1, 1, 'V1');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (1, 2, 'V2');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (1, 3, 'V3');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (1, 4, 'V4');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (2, 1, 'V5');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (2, 2, 'V6');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (2, 3, 'V7');
insert into @t2 (id1, rev, code) values (3, 1, 'V8');


with
ranked_revisions as (
select
  id1, 
  rev, 
  code,
  row_number() over (partition by id1 order by rev desc) as rowid
from 
  @t2 t2
),

latest_revisions as (
select
  id1,
  rev,
  code
from
  ranked_revisions
where
  rowid = 1
)

select
  t1.id2, 
  t1.title, 
  t2.rev, 
  t2.code
from
  @t1 t1
  inner join latest_revisions t2 on
    t1.id1 = t2.id1
```

This returns:

```
id2 title   rev code
D1  TITLE1  4   V4
D2  TITLE2  3   V7
D3  TITLE3  1   V8
```

The longer answer though is that there is a lot of variability in how to get this row_number() functionality in different flavors of SQL.  The overall strategy is to get a row number (partitioned on each category) starting with 1 for the row you want to keep, then just query out those rowid = 1 rows.

The subqueries (CTE's, here) only run once per query run, not once per row, so they're not much of a burden from a performance perspective.

Comment: Apart from the `@t1` table name, this is pretty much standard SQL and will work with any modern DBMS.